# My WordCloud is missing the letter 's' at the end of words

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, word-cloud

At first I thought the problem is with my data and that I made a mistake while cleaning the data. However I checked it and that is not the case.

I am using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

allWords = ' '.join([twts for twts in df['full_text']])
wordCloud = WordCloud(collocations=True, width = 1000,
height=600, random_state = 21, max_font_size = 120).generate(allWords)

plt.imshow(wordCloud, interpolation = "bilinear")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Now my wordcloud shows words like "coronaviru", "viru", "crisi".With `collocations=True` it shows the full words in combination with other words like "coronavirus case" "coronavirus pandemic".
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Like I said, I checked the data and it is always the correct full word there. So I guess the mistake happens with the wordcloud.

My data looks like this:

```
    created_at                        id                full_text
0   Sat Aug 01 00:25:53 +0000 2020    28934685093219    life is hard with coronavirus
1   Sat Aug 01 00:25:53 +0000 2020    28934685093219    coronavirus sucks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to change a parameter in the WordCloud function: **normalize_plurals=False**.
Reference: https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html

> normalize_plurals: bool, default=True. Whether to remove trailing ‘s’
> from words. If True and a word appears with and without a trailing
> ‘s’, the one with trailing ‘s’ is removed and its counts are added to
> the version without trailing ‘s’ – unless the word ends with ‘ss’.
> Ignored if using generate_from_frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something wrong, your code works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud

array = {'full_text': ['life is hard with coronavirus', 'coronavirus sucks']}
df = pd.DataFrame(array)

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
allWords = ' '.join([twts for twts in df['full_text']])
wordCloud = WordCloud(collocations=True, width = 1000,
height=600, random_state = 21, max_font_size = 120).generate(allWords)

plt.imshow(wordCloud, interpolation = "bilinear")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: When I try it with specific rows that contain for example "coronavirus". The wordcloud for that row shows the "coronavirus" spelled correctly. As soon as I apply it to the whole dataset I get the wordcloud with `coronaviru`. I searched through the dataset column in excel (hate me) with a filter and only found the word correctly spelled. Really dont know what the problem can be.
EDIT: Also checked it in the code with `df.full_text.str.count("coronavirus").sum()` and its equal to `f.full_text.str.count("coronaviru").sum()`. So its always correctly spelled

Comment: So how do you explain that the code above works? What else do you do with the DF?

Comment: I do nothing else. I use exactly that code. my ideas are (keep in mind i am quite a rookie): the structure of the DF might be flawed in some way. I had problems with that earlier. But looking at it now it looks perfect. Maybe it has something to do with \s thing but no clue. Another naiv idea is that the wordcloud plugin is trying to not show words as plurals and is cutting of the "s" for that reason. Wouldn't make too much sense though and I didn't find anything regarding that.

Comment: I kind of fixed it now by adding the wrongly spelled words to the stopword list so they are excluded. Now the wordcloud actually shows the rightly spelled words with similiar size. Very weird. Still no idea what is causing the root problem.

Comment: It should not behave this way